# How to change the Top bar's icon color

Tags: icons, menu, colors, taskbar

The power, wireless, sound, and battery icon are black on my Top bar. I am wondering how I can change the color of these icons to a lighter color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to change your `icon theme`. Most flavors of Ubuntu ship more than one icon theme by default. How exactly you change from one to the other depends on your desktop environment (DE) because some DEs allow for changing the icon theme using a GUI available by default while others may require use of the command line interface (CLI) or the installation of additional software such as Ubuntu Tweak or GNOME Tweak Tools, MyUnity, Unsettings, etc.

Here is a snapshot of "Customize Look and Feel" that Lubuntu 12.10 comes with. The active tab relates to icons themes:

[image: Lubuntu' GUI]

Here are two images of my "top bar" using different icon themes:

modified "elementary Dark"
[image: elementary Dark]

modified "Humanity"
[image: Humanity]

Apart from the icon themes shipped by default, you can download others from "the internet". You could also change specific icons to suit your needs rather than changing the entire icon theme.